# Export multiple models to a single model file using Autodesk Forge API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I have loaded multiple Revit files in Autodesk Forge viewer. Now I want to export a single SVF or Revit file (Merged all model contents into a single file) from the viewer.

Could you please help me to solve above problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the viewer is used to viewing models only. It doesn't have the capabilities of editing or generating models, unfortuantely. So, I'd advise you to do the following:

1. Open either of the Revit models with Revit Desktop or [Design Automation API for Revit](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/about_this_tutorial/) as the host model, and link others as linked RVTs.
2. Save the changes into the host RVT.
3. Package host and linked RVT files into a ZIP file.
4. Upload the ZIP to your OSS bucket
5. Submit a composite Revit file translation job with the below job configuration for example, or see See https://youtu.be/nfHZLlWtQ-0?t=114

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer  \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
   "input": {
     "urn": "{URN_OF_THE_ZIP}",
     "compressedUrn": true,
     "rootFilename": "host_rvt_filename.rvt"
   },
   "output": {
     "formats": [
       {
         "type": "svf",
         "views": [
           "2d",
           "3d"
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
 }'
```

6. Load the translated URN from step 5. This is the single URN containing the host and linked contents.